# I'm new to PHP and I created a For loop and would like to know if anyone knows how to re-write it to a while loop?

Tags: php

This is the code I have. It currently works as is, However I'm experimenting with loops and want to see it can be done with a while loop and how it would be done. With this code I can take 2 input numbers and display them, then point out all odds, add all evens, and add all the squares of the odds.

```
define ("B","<br/>");

$firstNum = $_POST["firstNum"];
$secondNum = $_POST["secondNum"];

if ($firstNum < $secondNum)
{
    $firstNum = true;
}
    elseif ($firstNum >= $secondNum)
    {
        $firstNum = "You didn't listen, dumb dumb!".'<br/><a href="Assignment5form.php">GO BACK</a>';
    }

echo "First Number: ".$firstNum."<br/>"."Second Number: ".$secondNum;

echo B;
echo B;

$numbers = array();
$numbers = range($firstNum, $secondNum);
$length = count($numbers);
$odds = array();
$sumSqOdds = 0;
$sumEven = 0;
$j = 0;


for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++)
    {
        if (($numbers[$x] % 2) == 1)
        {
            $odds[$j] = $numbers[$x];
            $sumSqOdds = $sumSqOdds + pow ($numbers[$x], 2);
            $j++;
        }
        else 
        {
            $sumEven = $sumEven + $numbers[$x];
        }
    }

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

printf("The odd numbers between your integers are: ");

for ($x = 0; $x < $j; $x++)
    {
        echo $odds[$x];
        echo '&nbsp;';
        $y++;
        if (($y % 10) == 0)
        {
            echo B;
        }
    }

echo B;
echo B;

printf("The sum of all even numbers between your integers is: ".$sumEven);

echo B;
echo B;

printf("The sum of the square of the odd numbers between your integers is: ".$sumSqOdds);
```

Here is my while loop but it seems to be infinite...

```
$numW = array ();
$numW = range ($firstNum, $secondNum);
$lengthW = count ($numW);
$oddsW = array ();
$sumSqOddsW = 0;
$sumEvenW = 0;
$j = 0;
$x = 0;

while ($x < $lengthW)
{
    if (($numW[$x] % 2) == 1)
    {
        $oddsW[$j] = $numW[$x];
        $sumSqOddsW = $sumSqOddsW + pow ($numW[$x], 2);
        $x++;
        $j++;
    }
    else
    {
        $sumEvenW = $sumEvenW + $numW[$x];
    }
}

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

printf ("The odd numbers between your integers are: ");

while ($x < $j)
{
    $x++;
    echo $oddsW[$x];
    echo "nbsp;";
    $y++;
    if (($y % 10) == 0)
    {
        echo B;
    }
}
```

Comment: For arrays you are better off learning: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a loop to ever finish it has to change one of the two evaluating variables. So either $x, or $lengthW would have to change during iteration.
 You made an if statment, in the first case you define that X increases by 1, but in the else case you do not change any variable that then has an effect on either $x, or $lengthW

Nor is there any check that sees if the else state has been reached and to catch that by either changing $x or $lengthW in a later iteration.


As such there's an infinite loop as soon as you reach the else case.


The if statement uses the same $x value as the last iteration checking the same position of the $numW, as such nothing has changed since the last iteration and you'll hit the else again, and again, and so on.

```
while ($x < $lengthW)
{
    if (($numW[$x] % 2) == 1)
    {
        $oddsW[$j] = $numW[$x];
        $sumSqOddsW = $sumSqOddsW + pow ($numW[$x], 2);
        $x++; //$x is increased by one, and as such, the loop will progress.
        // remove this $x++ if you place it outside the if else statement.
        $j++;
    }
    else // reached when ($numW[$x] %2) != 1
    {
        $sumEvenW = $sumEvenW + $numW[$x];
        // No changes to $x or $lengthW as such you'll hit the else again
        // this could be solved by either adding $x++; here.
    }
    // or by adding $x++; here 
    // (if you do add it here, remove it in the if case above, 
    // or you risk increasing it by 2 every iteration
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Equivalent loops:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  echo $i;
}

$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
  echo $i;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: I figured thats the route to go, thanks, However, I seem to keep running into an infinite loop. Unsure how to add my code to a comment so I edited the main post and added it there.